Delete dynamically columns that match a pattern in Azure Data Factory
I have a document with around 3000 columns.
Some of those column names start with ZN followed by a integer number like ZN2381.
I want to delete all columns that have a higher integer then 30. So ZN1 or ZN24 shall remain.
Everything above shall be discarded.
All the other columns shall remain in the final output when they don't match that pattern.
How can this be achieved?
